# ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column ''ColumnName'' in 'field list'

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm using Connector/Python to update a MySQL database from a Python script.

```
update_table = ("UPDATE Users "
            "SET `%s` = %s "
            "WHERE Id = %s ")
cursor.execute(update_table, (columnname, value, id))
```

And I get this error:

#### ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column ''ColumnName'' in 'field list'

while I do have a column called ColumnName. I think there's some problem with the quotes, i.e. it might be looking for 'ColumnName' instead of ColumnName, but, for example, if I remove the backticks (`) and the update_table looks like this:

```
update_table = ("UPDATE Users "
            "SET %s = %s "
            "WHERE Id = %s ")
cursor.execute(update_table, (columnname, value, id))
```

I get this other error:

#### ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ColumnName' = 'Somebody' WHERE Id = '0000'' at line 1

Any idea about how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First learn SQL syntax. 1. Don't use quotes for column name. 2. Use quotes for values. 3. backticks (`) is not correct quotation marks.

Comment: why not put it all into one string as well? `update_table = (""" ... """)` u can use the three quote marks for multiline string

Comment: Keeping backticks (as in my first snippet, tells me that the syntaxis is correct, but it keeps looking for a "ColumnName" instead of ColumnName. Instead, removing the backticks, as you suggest (and as I show in my second snippet), throws a programming error. Does anybody have an exact clue about what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the ones wondering about how I solved this problem:

```
update_table = ("""UPDATE Users 
SET %s = '%s' 
WHERE Id = '%s' """)
cursor.execute(update_table%(columnname, value, id))
```

Thanks to furas and John Ruddell for the tips.